# Dynamic Axes with a custom RNN

Tags: cntk

I’m running into a number of issues relating to dynamic axes. I am trying to implement a convolutional rnn similar to the of the LSTM() function but handles sequential image input and outputs an image.

I’m able to build the network and pass dummy data through it to produce output, but when I try to compute the error with an input_variable label I consistently see the following error:

```
RuntimeError: Node '__v2libuid__Input471__v2libname__img_label' (InputValue operation): DataFor: FrameRange's dynamic axis is inconsistent with matrix: {numTimeSteps:1, numParallelSequences:2, sequences:[{seqId:0, s:0, begin:0, end:1}, {seqId:1, s:1, begin:0, end:1}]} vs. {numTimeSteps:2, numParallelSequences:1, sequences:[{seqId:0, s:0, begin:0, end:2}]}`
```

If I understand this error message correctly, it claims that the value I passed in as the label has inconsistent axes to what is expected with 2 time steps and 1 parallel sequence, when what is desired is 1 time-step and 2 sequences. This makes sense to me, but I’m not sure how the data I’m passing in is not conforming to this. Here are (roughly) the variable declarations and eval statements:

```
…
img_input = input_variable(shape=img_shape, dtype=np.float32, name="img_input")
convlstm = Recurrence(conv_lstm_cell, initial_state=initial_state)(img_input)
out = select_last(convlstm)
img_label = input_variable(shape=img_shape, dynamic_axes=out.dynamic_axes, dtype=np.float32, name="img_label”)
error = squared_error(out, img_label)
…

dummy_input = np.ones(shape=(2, 3, 3, 32, 32))   # (batch, seq_len, channels, height, width)
dummy_label = np.ones(shape=(2, 3, 32, 32))        # (batch, channels, height, width)
out = error.eval({img_input:dummy_input, img_label:dummy_label})
```

I believe part of the issue is with the dynamic_axes set when creating the img_label input_variable, I’ve also tried setting it to [Axis.default_batch_axis()] and not setting it at all and either squared error complains about inconsistent axes between out and img_label or I see the same error as above.

Answer (score 0):

The only issue I see with the above setup is that your dummy label should have an explicit dynamic axis so it should be declared as

```
dummy_label = np.ones(shape=(2, 1, 3, 32, 32))
```

Assuming your `convlstm` works similar to an lstm, then the following works without issues for me and it evaluates the loss for two input/output pairs.

```
x = C.input_variable((3,32,32))
cx = convlstm(x)
lx = C.sequence.last(cx)
y = C.input_variable(lx.shape, dynamic_axes=lx.dynamic_axes)
loss = C.squared_error(y, lx)
x0 = np.arange(2*3*3*32*32,dtype=np.float32).reshape(2,3,3,32,32)
y0 = np.arange(2*1*3*32*32,dtype=np.float32).reshape(2,1,3,32,32)
loss.eval({x:x0, y:y0})
```